# Kubernetes vs mesos+marathon vs juju - how to demystify?

Tags: juju

[somewhat newbie]
Stumbled across juju 2 nights ago when looking for ways to use Ganglia and/or Rocks for cluster management and monitoring.  Love the "deploy on AWS, yada-yada..." of Juju - almost seems like holy grail of deployment to me.

Then I started reading on building charms... and noticed that there are charms (experimental?) for Kubernetes.  If I have juju, why would I need Kubernetes ? or Mesos ? or Typesafe ConductR (new proprietary product) ?

There is also a ganglia charm... if juju is doing monitoring, why do I need ganglia charm?  Are there any heuristics for what are "good candidates" for charms?

Thanks,
S-

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes is a great technology for managing a cluster of containers.  It does that very well, but only works with containers.  Juju is more about service orchestration, dealing with virtual machines and also can orchestrate containers.  Juju can install and configure a Kubernetes cluster on GCE or AWS or any of the public clouds. Giving users the option to evaluate, develop, or use Kubernetes without having to know the details of the setup.

While Juju does monitor the services it deploys, it is not a true monitoring system like Ganglia or Nagios.  Again you can deploy the services with Juju to build a solution with monitoring and save that to what is called a bundle.  You can then repeat that deployment of the bundled solution to other clouds if needed.

A good candidate for a charm is any software service that you need or use.  There are many available at http://jujucharms.com, you can download those and use them now.  If you don't see something there that you know and use, that would be a "good candidate" for a charm.  Some people know certain software very well those would be a good candidate for [writing a new charm](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/authors-charm-writing).

Comment: I have problems to understand the fact that kubernetes deals only with containers. Is it not created to scale horizontally and deal with others nodes (hosts) so we can divide the traffic. Also If we use juju as Kubernetes_provider, do we will have multiples kubernates master and nodes if we have multiple hosts?